# Upgraded ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.1.6, active_admin throws NoMethodError (active_admin.css.scss)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, capistrano, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

After upgrading my app from ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.6, accessing my Active Admin-powered admin interface threw the following error:

`NoMethodError - undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass
(in /Users/myusername/Rails/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)`

I replicated this error when simply accessing an Active Admin page, and when doing a rake assets:precompile (which happens during a deploy as well).

I tried completely commenting out the contents of `active_admin.css.scss`, to no avail. My relevant gem versions:

- activeadmin (0.5.1)
- sass (3.4.13)
- sass-rails (3.2.6)
- bootstrap-sass (2.1.1.0)
- rails (3.2.21)

What happened between ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1.6 that might be causing this error with stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/macfanatic/SprintApp/issues/27), sass gem 3.1.18 is the first SASS gem release with ruby-2.x compatibility. This led me down the path of upgrading my sass-rails gem from 3.2.4 to 3.2.6, which as a dependency upgraded my sass gem to 3.4.13 (was 3.1.15).

And that did it! No more obscure errors related to `active_admin.css.scss` or css in general.

**UPDATE**

sass-rails didn't really need to be updated. Just the sass gem solves the problem (also, upgrading sass-rails inexplicably broke some javascript in the app, specifically it triggered the error `History.js Core has already been loaded...` found in jquery.history.js).